# Core Data structure issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, xcode, core-data

I'm new to Core Data and I can't figure out how to make a proper structure of my database.

I have two entities: **bank** and **person**.

I believe that many to many relationship should be used, because there will be many banks and every person will have account in several banks.

*bank #1: 1.John 2.Andrew 3.Nick*

*bank #2: 1.Andrew 2.Nick 3.John*

*bank #3: 1.Nick 2.Henry*

As we can see **bank** #1 has many **persons**. Also **person** Andrew have accounts in several **banks**.

The question is: How to achieve such structure where the order of **persons** in every **bank** matter and we don't know the exact number of **banks** / **persons**

Comment: Why does the order of persons matter?

Comment: If you are going for C language then go for a 2 struct's and create an varialble of one struct with in a struct   or if C++/Java/any other high level language then write 2 classes and create an object of one class with in other and use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bank  <<-- Account -->> Person
```

Comment: Just use the third entity?

Comment: This also works Account is an entity with 2 objects Bank and Person